# Image size guidelines

Tags: image, image-processing, performance

This may well be a little of an open-ended question

The site I am working on requires to be optimised for performance. One of the key areas is to optimise the file sizes of the images used upon the site.

Unfortunatley these images are being created by employees who do not have the required knowledge for creating images for the web, and it is my job to produce a set of guidelines for them to use.

I was wondering whether there was any resource/guidlines/literature regarding typical images file sizes for images of different dimensions - as I would like to include something like this to aid them to ensure their images are being created properly.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer the opinion question, but I can suggest some guidelines that will keep your images smaller.

First off, if they're using Photoshop to edit their images, it's likely they're storing a whole bunch of crap in the headers (digital papertrail, EXIF data, and such).  Also, folks will frequently save in too high a bit depth.

For novice users, trying to explain why they need to use "save for web" is more likely to confuse them.  Instead, just point them at:

http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/

This site is rather handy - it will compress all the images on a page you specify, or you can upload the images.

You should strongly consider writing some guidelines about where images are stored as well.  It's frequently very beneficial to have your static image content stored on several servers, apart from your dynamic content.  Most browsers will only download a limited # of files at a time from any given website (usually it's 2).

Unless there's a good reason, all your images should be cached using one of the HTTP cache techniques (expires, etags, etc).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful, out of interest my team are debating whether you would should a gradient as a gif or JPG? Traditionally I would opt for JPG

Comment: Generally images with least colour variation such as logos should be either gif or png, photographic images and images with grads are best as jpg

Answer (score 0):

72 dpi as a resolution and either jpeg or png formats work best.

Try to use images at the exact pixel area size they will end up being displayed as. This is specified by the images height and width attributes.

You can set the output quality of a jpeg image which will also save file size although there is a trade off against image quality.

I hope this is of use.